# Nested for-loop the pythonic way to structure data?

Tags: python, nested-loops

I have structured data in some sources and ultimately I would like to step through each source, by the same amount, but starting at different indexes, in order to re-structure the data.

I will go on to perform analysis on each item contained in each iterated slice of source. What is the python way to do this? A nested for loop?

```
sources = ('source1', 'source2' 'source3')
for source in sources:
    slices = ('[1::5]', '[2::5]''[3::5]')
    for slice in slices:
        iteratedSlice = source[slice]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nested for loop with [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice) is a good starting point:

```
sources = [source1, source2, source3]
slices = [slice(1,None,5), slice(2,None,5), slice(3,None,5)]

for source in sources:
    for s in slices:
        iteratedSlice = source[s]
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `slice` as the variable in the inner loop.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks for the eye

Comment: Using tuple instead of list as OP do is "better" in my opinion. Also, possibly less verbose: `slices = [slice(n, None, 5) for n in (1, 2, 3)]`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a better way of doing what you need, but we're going to need give up more information. What are you going to do with your *iteratedSlice* variable?

```
sources = ('source1', 'source2' 'source3')

for source in sources:
    for n in range(1, 4):
        iteratedSlice = source[n:5]
```

Comment: each item of the slice, is a string. I am going to split the string in order to append the first word/number to an empty object that is specific to each iterated slice, transform the lists to  np.arrays, stack the arrays, learn how to use pandas, transform matrix into a DataFrame.

Comment: *specific to each resource